# Give the name of this "outlaw"

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, lateral-thinking

Who/what am I?

I am a

stunning fresh shiny bandit

HINT:

> "I have" a Caribbean origin. I silently hunt down my prey in the dark. It is hard to catch me

HINT2:

> I am tall or long

HINT3:

> I am in danger everyday

HINT4:

> It is not a rare thing that my taste changes from salty to sweet

Comment: You've posted a lot of puzzles recently that nobody's been able to solve - could you give a hint on some of your earlier ones before sharing new ones? (You use a lot of similar phrases in each of them, so a solution to one of them may help us figure out what you're looking for on your newer ones.)

Answer (score 6):

Is the outlaw

> [Long John Silver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_John_Silver) ?
>
>  stunning - his one-legged parrot-carrying likeness is a sight to behold
>  fresh - could be a reference to the seafood chain [Long John Silver's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_John_Silver%27s)
>  shiny - reference to the metallic part of his name
>  bandit - he was a pirate in the novel Treasure Island